# What's different between "su - username" then command and "sudo -u username command"

Tags: sudo, libraries, su

I have a problem about unixodbc. It show the error message about `Can't open lib ....`
So, I use the `ldd` command to check.

If I use `su - username`,the result like below:

```
[root@ostest ~]# su - mysql  
[mysql@ostest ~]$ ldd /usr/local/oraclient112/libsqora.so.11.1  
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6c11d000)  
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb08a932000)  
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb08a6ad000)  
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb08a490000)  
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fb08a277000)  
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => /usr/local/oraclient112/libclntsh.so.11.1(0x00007fb087d46000)  
        libodbcinst.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.1 (0x00007fb087b35000)  
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb0877a1000)  
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b02000000)  
        libnnz11.so => /usr/local/oraclient112/libnnz11.so (0x00007fb0873d8000)  
        libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007fb0871d7000)  
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fb086fce000)  


[root@ostest ~]# sudo -u mysql ldd /usr/local/oraclient112/libsqora.so.11.1  
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3d5ff000)  
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8eaec7a000)  
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8eae9f5000)  
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8eae7d8000)  
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f8eae5bf000)  
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found  
        libodbcinst.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.1 (0x00007f8eae3ad000)  
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8eae019000)  
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b02000000)  
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f8eade0f000)
```

If I use `sudo -u username`, I can't find the `libodbcinst.so.1` library.

- What's different between `sudo` and `su`?
- How could it work with `sudo -u`?

Comment: I don't know the details, but `su -` will create a completely new environment, as if you had logged in on a tty as that user. `sudo -u username` will execute the command as the provided user, but use your environment.

Answer (score 2):

The `mysql` account environment is likely defining the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable or something similar.

`su -` is dropping your environment and use `mysql`'s one just like if `mysql` had logged in. On the other hand, `sudo` is only keeping some variables of your own environment, and definitely not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as that would be a security issue.

If it is the case, this should work:

```
sudo -u mysql -i ldd /usr/local/oraclient112/libsqora.so.11.1
```

You might also explicitly set the required variable that way:

```
sudo -u mysql LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/oraclient112/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd /usr/local/oraclient112/libsqora.so.11.1
```

Comment: More or less the correct answer... `-i` provides some kind of equivalence to `su -`. It's incorrect to say `su -` is "cleaning" the environment. It's really populating the environment with the defaults as if the target user had _logged in_, telling the shell to behave as if this is a login, which in many cases, means the shell initializes with (for instance) reading `.bash_profile`. Anything in there that sets the environment will affect the runtime of the program being executed. `sudo`, by contrast, cleans the environment while allowing (by default) a whitelist of variables to get passed thru

Comment: @Otheus By cleaning (clearing) the environment, I meant using `su -` is dropping the current user's environment (before setting it to the target user's one) contrasting with `su` alone which keeps it. You are correct `sudo` is not keeping most of the user's environment. I'll rephrase that to make it clearer.